# need to create fake directory path for my css but actual path is executed in server

Tags: .htaccess, osclass

I need to fake a path in view page source by user (by right clicking my website and seeing my source code)
for example 
`<link href="http://miads.in/oc-content/themes/modern/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
and the path `http://miads.in/oc-content/themes/modern/style.css` to `http://miads.in/pc-content/style/look/style.css`.

I tried to write in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oc-content/(themes)/(modern)/([a-z]+)\.(css)$ /pc-content/style/look/$4.$5 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it does not change any path in viewer point(view source) and in source it shows the css file original path, but style of my page is gone and only text remains.

Comment: Of course, you cannot change/fake the url which is already in user's browser. In short words, you can't achieve that.

Comment: Question: why do you want to change what user is seeing?

Comment: thnks for your support

Comment: You're welcome. There are ways to obfuscate the content if that is what you want. But remember that obfuscated content in browser can easily be deobfuscated. Only lazy or non-tehnical users will not deobfuscate the content.